# Bad Access error for updateLabels method

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Am getting a bad access error for an updateLabels method, but can't figure it out. Here is the code:

BullsEyeViewController.m

```
#import "BullsEyeViewController.h"

@interface BullsEyeViewController ()

@end

@implementation BullsEyeViewController
{
    int _currentValue;
    int _targetValue;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self startNewRound];
    [self updateLabels];
}

-(void)startNewRound
{
    _targetValue = 1 + arc4random_uniform(100);
    _currentValue = 50;
    self.slider.value = _currentValue;
}

-(void)updateLabels
{
    self.targetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _targetValue]; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2)
    // Convert the int into a string so that it will fit in the label as an outlet
    [self updateLabels];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)showAlert
{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The value of the slider is: %d\nThe target value is %d", _currentValue, _targetValue];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Hello World"
          message:message
         delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertView show];

    [self startNewRound];
}

-(IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)slider
{
    _currentValue = lroundf(slider.value);
}

@end
```

Comment: You are flooding your memory thanks to infinite recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's calling itself infinitely.  Don't do this unconditionally inside updateLabels...

```
[self updateLabels];
```

Comment: OOPS! Should have had [self updateLabels]; in the viewDidLoad and showAlert methods. Now that I fixed it, it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `updateLabels` from inside `updateLabels`? The crash is due to the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your `updateLabels` method calls itself and is creating an infinite loop. Did you mean `[super updateLabels]`?